# Watching for file changes with StatReloader Exception in thread django-main-thread:

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

**Don't know what the problem is. I am not able to run any of my Django servers.
    Every time gets the same error.
And don't have any idea about this.
Tried reinstalling windows, python and all. But still gets same error.
**
Don't know what the problem is. I am not able to run any of my Django servers.
    Every time gets the same error.
And don't have any idea about this.
Tried reinstalling windows, python and all. But still gets same error.

```
C:\Users\JamesBond\Desktop\ONLINE WEBSITES\vishwatradelink_>manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\Desktop\ONLINE WEBSITES\vishwatradelink_\manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 598, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 583, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 301, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 307, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 347, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 363, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 262, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 103, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 139, in iter_modules_and_files
    if not path.exists():
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 1346, in exists
    self.stat()
  File "C:\Users\JamesBond\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 1168, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message that you are getting check there is a line:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms'
```

This means in your settings.py file you have 'crispy_forms' among the installed apps but this time its not included in your python environment. To resolve this you have to install crispy_forms using

> pip install django-crispy-forms

For more on django-crispy-forms see the documentation https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Answer (score 5):

Run the following commands:
(write python according to your OS this commands below are for windows)

1) python manage.py makemigrations

and then

2) python manage.py migrate

Mostly, this will make your command 
python manage.py runserver work!

Answer (score 1):

> **No module named 'crispy_forms'

this is the problem

OR 
command is `python manage.py runserver`, not `manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have added the name of my app before creating that app in the settings.py file of the main project. Kindly add  the name of your app in settings.py file after creating the app. That's why you are not able to run the server

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem, go to the `settings.py` file, and check for comas, and if `rest_framework` is correctly spelled.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to be in the right virtual environment you previously worked on because everything you previously installed like `rest_framework`, `django` will be stored in that environment, and try running the command.

```sh
python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

At first I tried the first comment, after running each command prompt it is giving me errors.Like after I run this command`python manage.py makemigrations` It is giving me almost the same error.Then I run the second command'python manage.py migrate' now it is also giving me the same error.Then I run the `python manage.py runserver` then it is giving me the same error.After I read the second comment.Then I have gotten some kinda idea about what is wrong here.Then I found one line at the end of error which is generated in my system 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'widget_tweaks' This line is almost same with the given error line at the second comment 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms'.Then I install the missing module.But this is not enough.After this then I again run this command 'python manage.py runserver' now it is giving me a differnt error.According to the error I have install that module to my system.I have do the same thing for 3 to 4 times.Then finally my project run.